# Show that $R/I$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

$R=\{a+ib:\ a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

$I=\{a+ib:\ 5\mid a\text{ and }5\mid b\}$

Ok so I wanted to create homomorphism from $R$ onto $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

$\phi(a+ib)=([a],[b])$ and while I think this is highly suggestive I can't show that $\phi((a+ib)(c+id))=\phi(a+ib)\phi(c+id)$

Should I try another approach  and if not , any hint about how to prove equality above would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get it , why is $ø(a+ib)=[a] + i[b] $ ? What's the point of having $i$ in the picture

Comment: Ah ok , can you explain to me why $([a] [c] - [b][d])+i([a][d] + [b][c]) = ([a]+i[b])([c] +i[d])$. I got to one step behind this myself but I couldn't see this and I still can't see why is this?

Comment: Hint: write $\mathbb Z[i] = \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1)$. Can you compute the latter ring mod $5$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Try $\phi(a+ib)=(a-2b,a+2b)$.